# Use multiple modules in one Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I am working on a project and have planned the following architecture within one single Android Studio project:

1) Eight custom library modules which I intend to reuse in future projects.

2) Three closely related apk modules which complement each other's functionality.

3) Five shared modules which would be used in above apk modules.

Is this the recommended approach to keep the project architecture modular, and reuse of modules in multiple projects, while ensuring performance of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have more RAM for bigger projects , atleast 8 GB .

Lets say you have 2 apk modules and 1 library module that is being used by the 2 apk modules. If you find the compile times taking longer you can disable the apk module you are not working on temporarily and compile it faster .